# How can I trigger an error from inside gulp-esdoc?

Tags: javascript, git, documentation, gulp

I am using gulp-esdoc to generate my documentation (and it already works).

Today I added a git pre-commit hook, it launches multiples gulp tasks and prevent any commit if one of the tasks returns an error.

I works for most of my tasks, but for gulp-esdoc, I don't know how to return such an error to prevent the commit.

I configured my esdoc this way :

```
gulp.task('documentation', function() {
gulp.src("./client/")
    .pipe(esdoc({
        destination: "./docs",
        "title": "SOMETHING",
        index: "./README.md",
        "plugins": [{
            "name": "./README/docplugins/on-complete.js"
        }]
    }));
});
```

As you can see, I am using an esdoc plugin to do some code once the documentation has been generated, here is the code for the plugin :

```
var colors = require('colors'),
gutil = require('gulp-util');

exports.onComplete = function(ev) {

    var output = require('../../docs/coverage.json');

    var expectedCoverage = 100; // todo : get from option instead
    var percentCovered = (output.actualCount / output.expectCount) * 100;

    if (percentCovered < expectedCoverage) {
        console.log('Code coverage is not sufficient (expected ' + expectedCoverage + '%, received only ' + percentCovered + '%) !!! Write some documentation or get out !'.red);
        // return false; // todo
    } else {
        console.log('Code coverage is complete, well done :)'.green);
        // return true;
    }

};
```

The main goal here is to return an error if my code documentation is not 100% covered (the code logic is working, if a comment is missing in my JS code, I go into the line with the "todo".

Finally, here is my (simplified) git-hook (in my gulpfile) :

```
gulp.task('pre-commit', function () {
    gulp.start('lint');
    gulp.start('documentation');
});
```

The 'lint' part works, it prevent commit if I have an error in my code. But the 'documentation' code, using gulp-esdoc, doesn't return any error, so the commit is done :( I don't know what to do to return an error and prevent the git commit.

I need to do this because I want the junior developers joining my team to be forced to document their code :p

Thanks for helping !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to throw a [`PluginError`](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp-util#new-pluginerrorpluginname-message-options):

```
throw new gutil.PluginError('esdoc', 'Something broke');
```

This will cause your gulp process to exit with a non-zero exit code. It will however leave a rather ugly stack trace on `STDERR` (especially since `gulp-esdoc` rethrows errors from plugins).

Another option then is to explicitly exit the process with a specific exit code:

```
process.exit(1);
```

The [`process`](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process) object in Node.js is a global object and can be accessed from anywhere without having to `require()` it.